# Unable to customize Rev Slider dimensions due to element.style

Tags: javascript, html, css, revolution-slider

I am trying to change the height of rev slider from 100% to 80% but can't find the code to do so. But when I inspect in Chrome I see:

```
element.style {
    max-height: 1080px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 902px;
}

element.style {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: none;
}
```

How do I edit or override element.style?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3koM.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JHf6.png)

[Here's the live site](http://test.jedidahalagbe.com/)

Answer (score 0):

These are inline CSS styles, however the correct way is to identify from where these are being added but you can override this using `!important`.

```
.tp-revslider-mainul{
   height: 80% !important;
}
```